# How can I fix a NulPointerException in this line?

Tags: nullpointerexception

I am coding UNO and want to make a method to check if the player can throw a card mathcing that on the table. If not, then method return true and the player can draw extra cards. If a match can be made, then the method returns false and the player can not draw cards.

I have made a label for the card on the table, called discardpileLabel and an JButton arraylist for the players cards. The method isValid() is called when draw button is clicked.

```
public boolean isValid ()
{
    int i = 0; 
    do
    {
        if ((discardpileLabel.getName()).charAt(0) == (playersCards2.get(i)).getName()).charAt(0) 
            ||(discardpileLabel.getName()).charAt(1) == ((playersCards2.get(i)).getName()).charAt(1))
        {
           return false;  
        } else i++; 
   } while (i < playersCards2.size()); 
   return true; 
}
```

I want the nullPointerException on the if statement to go away.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to throw Custom Exceptions

Check : [Custom Exception C#](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/custom-exception-csharp)